# make a comparison between two sagemaker-trained models using step functions

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, aws-step-functions

as the title says, I am trying to find a way to make a comparison between two models trained in sagemaker, using a step functions.
The cycle currently looks like this:
Start training, save the model, a lambda is run that checks if the accuracy was greater than 90 percent, if it is met: a batch job is started, if it is not met: the cycle is terminated.
What I would like to be able to deploy is a solution that instead of being compared to 90% accuracy, that is compared to a previous training.
I am currently using the Step Functions Data Science SDK.

Answer (score 1):

With Step Functions: Save a json file in S3 with previous model evaluation results, and have a Lambda step to compare current and previous results.

Also consider using SageMaker Pipelines instead of Step Functions. As [SageMaker Pipelines is integrated with SageMaker Experiments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/build-and-manage-propertyfile.html), you'll add this conditional logic:

In the evaluation step (processing job) get the accuracy values of the previous executions and compute the best. This will be done via Python code in the processing script. Then, generate a JSON file that contains both the accuracy value for the current execution and the best value across the past executions.
Define a conditional step that uses a [PropertyFile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/build-and-manage-propertyfile.html) and JsonGet expression to read from the JSON file both the left side and right side of the condition, in order to get a condition like [accuracy > previous_best_accuracy].

Comment: Hi,that makes a lot of sense to me. thank you very much
Do you have an idea or any help you could give me for the design of those lambda's? 
that within the same flow I can query a job = n and then I can query a different job = b so that these two can then be compared?